# Vagrant - Message: Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 9 column 1

Tags: vagrant, symfony

When I am running the

```
vagrant up
```

I get error:

```
There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: /Users/darius/PhpstormProjects/api.notification.guru/Vagrantfile
Line number: 0
Message: Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 9 column 1
```

The vagrant file looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# # vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'fileutils'

Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"

CLOUD_CONFIG_PATH = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "cloud-config")
CONFIG = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "vm-config.rb")
CA_CERT_PATH = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "certs/domain.pem")

# Defaults for config options defined in CONFIG
$num_instances = 1
$instance_name_prefix = "core"
$update_channel = "stable"
$image_version = "current"
$enable_serial_logging = false
$share_home = false
$vm_gui = false
$vm_memory = 1024
$vm_cpus = 1
$shared_folders = {}
$forwarded_ports = {}

# Attempt to apply the deprecated environment variable NUM_INSTANCES to
# $num_instances while allowing config.rb to override it
if ENV["NUM_INSTANCES"].to_i > 0 && ENV["NUM_INSTANCES"]
  $num_instances = ENV["NUM_INSTANCES"].to_i
end

if File.exist?(CONFIG)
  require CONFIG
end

# Use old vb_xxx config variables when set
def vm_gui
  $vb_gui.nil? ? $vm_gui : $vb_gui
end

def vm_memory
  $vb_memory.nil? ? $vm_memory : $vb_memory
end

def vm_cpus
  $vb_cpus.nil? ? $vm_cpus : $vb_cpus
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # always use Vagrants insecure key
  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.box = "coreos-%s" % $update_channel
  if $image_version != "current"
      config.vm.box_version = $image_version
  end
  config.vm.box_url = "http://%s.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/%s/coreos_production_vagrant.json" % [$update_channel, $image_version]

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    # On VirtualBox, we don't have guest additions or a functional vboxsf
    # in CoreOS, so tell Vagrant that so it can be smarter.
    v.check_guest_additions = false
    v.functional_vboxsf     = false
  end

  # plugin conflict
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-vbguest") then
    config.vbguest.auto_update = false
  end

  (1..$num_instances).each do |i|
    config.vm.define vm_name = "%s-%02d" % [$instance_name_prefix, i] do |config|
      config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.name = "api.notification.guru-%s" % [vm_name]
      end

      config.vm.hostname = vm_name

      if $enable_serial_logging
        logdir = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "log")
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(logdir)

        serialFile = File.join(logdir, "%s-serial.txt" % vm_name)
        FileUtils.touch(serialFile)

        config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb, override|
          vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--uart1", "0x3F8", "4"]
          vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", serialFile]
        end
      end

      if $expose_docker_tcp
        config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2375, host: ($expose_docker_tcp + i - 1), auto_correct: true
      end

      $forwarded_ports.each do |guest, host|
        config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: guest, host: host, auto_correct: true
      end

      config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.gui = vm_gui
        vb.memory = vm_memory
        vb.cpus = vm_cpus
      end

      ip = "172.17.3.#{i+100}"
      config.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip

      # Uncomment below to enable NFS for sharing the host machine into the coreos-vagrant VM.
      config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/core/shared", id: "core", :nfs => true, :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']
      $shared_folders.each_with_index do |(host_folder, guest_folder), index|
        config.vm.synced_folder host_folder.to_s, guest_folder.to_s, id: "core-share%02d" % index, nfs: true, mount_options: ['nolock,vers=3,udp']
      end

      if $share_home
        config.vm.synced_folder ENV['HOME'], ENV['HOME'], id: "home", :nfs => true, :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp']
      end

      if File.exist?(CLOUD_CONFIG_PATH)
        config.vm.provision :file, :source => "#{CLOUD_CONFIG_PATH}", :destination => "/tmp/vagrantfile-user-data"
        config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "mv /tmp/vagrantfile-user-data /var/lib/coreos-vagrant/", :privileged => true
      end

      if File.exist?(CA_CERT_PATH)
        config.vm.provision :file, :source => "#{CA_CERT_PATH}", :destination => "/tmp/domain.pem"
        config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "mv /tmp/domain.pem /etc/ssl/certs/domain.pem && update-ca-certificates > /dev/null", :privileged => true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The syntax error should be in line 9. I asked to check my colleague, who also uses this - he said the line is the same, and he does not get error.

I saw in other similar posts to check yaml files, but I do not know which ones. I do not think that there are some associated ones with this error.

Its a symfony project and I see yml files only from some packages in vendor folder. So it should not have something to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure its really from this file - did you try to remove this line and the corresponding part below from Vagrantfile and check if it worked ?

Comment: I tried now, getting error then in another line: "Message: NameError: uninitialized constant CONFIG" which makes sense - cause CONFIG becomes not initializedd

Comment: clear but you should compare the vm-config.rb file with your colleague most probably it comes from there - thats why I said _and_ remove the corresponding part from Vagrantfile (meaning where the config is used)/ Look on line 9 of the file

Comment: He sent me by slack the file contents, so by copying some indentation was different but its the same. Then I checked in git repository and diff tool showed the files are identical. Which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was showing line number 9 not of vagrantfile. It crashed in earlier line:

```
CLOUD_CONFIG_PATH = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "cloud-config")
```

and then I saw cloud-config file had conflicts like

<<<<<<< HEAD

and it failed to read that file. I have no idea how those conflicts got there because cloud-config is not in git.

But after I copied the line from git cloud-config.dist file, there was a tempplate tag

```
discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/<token>
```

and run

```
vagrant up
```

this token was overwriten and machine was lauched.